# Is there a way to autohide the toolbar in Sumatra PDF?

Tags: sumatra-pdf

There's an option to hide the tool bar in Sumatra PDF under advanced sections:

[image]

Is there a way I can autohide instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: 
There is no autohide option, but <kbd>F11</kbd> and/or <kbd>F11</kbd> are convenient ways to get full-screen display.